# Plotting polynomial with given coefficients

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, julia

I'm trying to plot a polynomial with coefficients given in array:

- **input:** *[an,a(n-1),...,a0]*
- **output:**  plot of polynomial *an*x^n + a(n-1)*x^(n-1) + ... + a0*

I would like to use matplotlib polt() function so I can use it in my julia project. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tutorial [Polynomial functions with Python](https://www.python-course.eu/polynomial_class_in_python.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Julia's `Polynomials` package then something like this pattern will work:

`p = Poly(reverse(ais))  # Poly wants [a0, a1, ..., an]
xs = linspace(a, b, 100) # fill in a, b
plot(xs, p.(xs))`

If you are using `Plots`, the last two lines could be `plot(x->p(x), a, b)`.