# How to plot curve with given polynomial coefficients?

Tags: python, arrays, plot, polynomials, coefficients

using Python I have an array with coefficients from a polynomial, let's say

```
polynomial = [1,2,3,4]
```

which means the equation:
y = 4x³ + 3x² + 2x + 1
(so the array is in reversed order)

Now how do I plot this into a visual curve in the Jupyter Notebook?
There was a similar question:
[Plotting polynomial with given coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740169/plotting-polynomial-with-given-coefficients)
but I didn't understand the answer (like what is a and b?).

And what do I need to import to make this happen?

Comment: The question you linked has a comment with a link to a page that fully explains everything you want: https://www.python-course.eu/polynomial_class_in_python.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to decide the limits for `x` in your plot. Let's say `x` goes from -2 to 2. Let's also ask for a hundred points on our curve (this can be any sufficiently large number for your interval so that you get a smooth-looking curve)

Let's create that array:

```
lower_limit = -2
upper_limit = 2
num_pts = 100
x = np.linspace(lower_limit, upper_limit, num_pts)
```

Now, let's evaluate `y` at each of these points. Numpy has a handy [`polyval()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) that'll do this for us. Remember that it wants the coefficients ordered by highest exponent to lowest, so you'll have to reverse the `polynomial` list

```
poly_coefs = polynomial[::-1] # [4, 3, 2, 1]
y = np.polyval(poly_coefs, x)
```

Finally, let's plot everything:

```
plt.plot(x, y, '-r')
```

[image]

You'll need the following imports:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

---

If you *don't* want to import `numpy`, you can also write vanilla python methods to do the same thing:

```
def linspace(start, end, num_pts):
    step = (end - start) / (num_pts - 1)
    return [start + step * i for i in range(num_pts)]

def polyval(coefs, xvals):
    yvals = []
    for x in xvals:
        y = 0
        for power, c in enumerate(reversed(coefs)):
            y += c * (x ** power)
        yvals.append(y)
    return yvals
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and easy to understand answer! What does the '-r' in plt.plot(x, y, '-r') mean? And how can I turn my coefficient array from [1,2,3,4] by code command into [4,3,2,1] without some complicated loop? Thank you!

Comment: `-r` plots the data using a line (`-`) that's colored red (`r`). Reversing array: It's already in the answer! `poly_coefs = polynomial[::-1]` Glad to help @cs_question_asker